# Overriding/Externalizing application.properties into docker-compose.yml

Tags: spring, docker

There are plenty of answers already but none of them solves my problem, please help!

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=****
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=portfolio
      - MYSQL_USER=manager
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=******
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "8010:3306"
  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "8005:8080"
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/portfolio
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=manager
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=******
      - SECRET_REGISTRATION_KEY=&&&&&&
    depends_on:
      - mysql
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

Inside my `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/portfolio_dev
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=manager
spring.datasource.password=$@(&%(@%(&%

secret.registration.key=[RANDOM_KEY]
```

**Expected behavior:** environment variable like `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` would override `spring.datasource.url` in `application.properties` in Spring Boot project.

**Actual behavior:** `api` container with Spring Boot inside does not pick up the environment variable in `docker-compose.yml`, defaulting to the ones inside `application.properties`.

**Reproduction:** I ran `docker-compose up --build` to make sure the JAR files are rebuilt and the mysql server runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is really a weird thing when a developer found his solution 10 minutes after posting his desperate StackOverflow question.

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64940105/15119843

The Spring Boot container starts up right after the mysql starts working, but not ready for connection, so the SB container could not connect to that one.

EDIT: Add `restart: on-failure` to the Spring Boot container. It restarts the api whenever a failure (that stops the process) as such occur.