# Spring boot docker container cannot establish connection to mySQL docker container

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

For some reason when the spring boot app is running in the container it can't connect to the MySQL container, I checked that the database container was up and running successfully by trying to connect to it from MySQL workbench and query data from it however that app itself fails to start up

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mydb
     container_name: mysql-db2
     environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
     ports:
      - 3306:3306

   demo:
        image: springboot
        container_name: my-spring-boot-app
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        environment:
            SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-db2:3306/mydb
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-db2:3306/mydb?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Dockerfile (MySQL)

```
FROM mysql
MAINTAINER me
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb \
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root

ADD springboot.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
EXPOSE 3306
```

Dockerfile (Spring boot)

```
FROM openjdk:20-ea-17-jdk
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

pom.xml (mySQL dependency version)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>8.0.31</version>
</dependency>
```

Log File

```
2022-12-29 14:24:14 
2022-12-29 14:24:14   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2022-12-29 14:24:14  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2022-12-29 14:24:14 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2022-12-29 14:24:14  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2022-12-29 14:24:14   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2022-12-29 14:24:14  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2022-12-29 14:24:14  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.0)
2022-12-29 14:24:14 
2022-12-29 14:24:14 2022-12-29T13:24:14.135Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.demo.application.DemoApplication     : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 20-ea with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2022-12-29 14:24:14 2022-12-29T13:24:14.144Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.e.demo.application.DemoApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-29 14:24:14 2022-12-29T13:24:14.734Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-29 14:24:14 2022-12-29T13:24:14.778Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 37 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-12-29 14:24:15 2022-12-29T13:24:15.502Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-29 14:24:15 2022-12-29T13:24:15.514Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-29 14:24:15 2022-12-29T13:24:15.514Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.1]
2022-12-29 14:24:15 2022-12-29T13:24:15.570Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-29 14:24:15 2022-12-29T13:24:15.572Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1327 ms
2022-12-29 14:24:15 2022-12-29T13:24:15.730Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-12-29 14:24:15 2022-12-29T13:24:15.767Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final
2022-12-29 14:24:15 2022-12-29T13:24:15.887Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2022-12-29 14:24:15 2022-12-29T13:24:15.968Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-12-29 14:24:17 2022-12-29T13:24:17.085Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2022-12-29 14:24:17 
2022-12-29 14:24:17 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2022-12-29 14:24:17 
2022-12-29 14:24:17 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1350) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1421) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at com.example.demo.application.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:15) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-12-29 14:24:17     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2022-12-29 14:24:17 Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2022-12-29 14:24:17
```

Comment: Is it possible your application is starting up before the database is ready, as in [docker compose problem while using spring boot mysql docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64938957/docker-compose-problem-while-using-spring-boot-mysql-docker)?  It looks like you're setting `spring.datasource.url` correctly and the Compose file looks reasonable.

Comment: @DavidMaze  I tried both suggestions mentioned in the answer you shared, It looks like I'm getting this error now 
`my-spring-boot-app  | java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.192.3' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to add below property to `application.properties` file.

**NOTE:** This solution needs restart of Spring Boot container alone separately after running docker-compose file. I think this is needed as MySQL takes some time to start-up.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-db2:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mydb
    build: /Users/MyiCloud/IdeaProjects/so/mysql/
    container_name: mysql-db2
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  demo:
    image: springboot
    build: /Users/MyiCloud/IdeaProjects/so/
    container_name: my-spring-boot-app
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-db2:3306/mydb
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>so</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```