# Spring boot + MySQL. Docker

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, docker-compose

I`m create simple app on spring boot + MySQL. On local pc it works correctly, but when i package it in docker, i catch some errors: container with DB works well, i can connect to it via workbanch, the container with the application crashes on startup with an error:
"java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
...
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
...
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
..."

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
ADD /target/tests-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar backend.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "backend.jar"]
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  personsdb:
    image: 'mysql:8.0.31'
    container_name: 'persons-db'
    environment:
      - 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Qwer'
      - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=persons'
      - 'MYSQL_USER=mysql'
      - 'MYSQL_PASSWORD=Qwer'
    ports:
      - '3305:3306'

  app:
    container_name: 'persons-app'
    ports:
      - 8088:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://personsdb:3305/persons?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    depends_on:
      - 'personsdb'
    build: ./
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://personsdb:3305/persons
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Qwer
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I tried to

1. run: docker-compose down --rmi all
2. rename service
3. upgrade MySQL Connector
4. add more dependences to pom.xml
   ...

Comment: Hi, solution is to add this property to application.properties file (spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect). Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74951832/spring-boot-docker-container-cannot-establish-connection-to-mysql-docker-contain/74954324#74954324

Comment: Thanks @VasanthSubramanian, i added this, but catched same error "java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up."

Comment: can you try datasource url as "jdbc:mysql://persons-db:3306/persons?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false" in both places (docker-compose.yml and application.properties file)

Comment: I tried to change url to "persons-db:3306", and to "persons-db:3305", deleted all containers and images... Always the same error.

Comment: @VasanthSubramanian you were right, "persons-db:3306" works! Big thanks and happy new year

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to create a bridge to let them communicate.

Please check the link below
https://www.tutorialworks.com/container-networking/

- when they are in the same host, below configuration also worked for me.

```
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/DB-NAME
```

Comment: I dont know why, but today it works. I changed nothing, just start my app and it works correct... Thanks everyone!