# Docker compose waiting for database to initialize

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

i have a problem, i have two services in docker compose, one with oracle database and second with springboot application.
Java app needs to wait for database to be created and wait for scripts to be initialized. Otherwise its throwing connection error.
I tried with health check and depends on but doenst work well
My docker-compose file:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  oracle-xe:
    image: gvenzl/oracle-xe:latest
    container_name: oracle
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
    environment:
      - ORACLE_PASSWORD=oracle
    volumes:
      - ../database/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - oracle-xe
```

Healthcheck, bash commands, depends on

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker compose problem while using spring boot mysql docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64938957/docker-compose-problem-while-using-spring-boot-mysql-docker)

Comment: No, i need something that waits for the database to initialize .sql scripts

Comment: Sure. You can define your own script to decide if the database initializing is done. In the linked answer you will see an example configuration. With a different healtcheck condition. Be creative :)

Comment: Yea, idk it doesnt work well for me :(